# target input value in the form to store in the localStorage after submitting the form and use the value for omdbapi

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, local-storage, omdbapi

I wanted to get the value in the input field after clicking the `search` button and set it in the `localStorage` then store it in the the `searchKey` variable and pass it in the `main()` to search the movies in omdbapi.

I tried using the `onsubmit` in the form and passed in the `browse(event)` to see if I can get the value in the input field. However, when I `console.log(event.target.value)` the input value is not showing up after clicking the `search` button.

```js
    const movieListEl = document.querySelector('.shows');
    const searchKey = localStorage.getItem("key");
    
    async function main (event) {
        const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
         const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
        const data = await search.json();
        // console.log(data.Search)
        movieListEl.innerHTML = data.Search.map((movie) => movieHTML(movie)).join("");
    
    }

    main(searchKey);

   function browse(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.value);
        localStorage.setItem("key", event.target.value); 
    }
    
    function movieHTML (details) {
    return `<div class="shows__content">
        <figure class="shows__poster">
            <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
        </figure>
           <div class="poster__description">
            <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
            <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        `
    }
```

```html
   

         <form action="" id="movie__searchbox" class="nav__search-bar" 
         onsubmit="browse(event)">
        <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="nav__search" placeholder="Search" />
        <button type="submit"  > 
      Search</button>
        </form>
     <div class="shows"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you get the value of the search button through [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)? The `event` object corresponds to the form submission as far as I remember so it's better to get it *directly*.

Also, inline attributes like `onsubmit()` are a bad practice, use the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method instead.

And, call the `main()` function, update local storage, and get `<input>`'s value when the form is submitted.

And, here's your final code.

*I commented everything related to local storage because it doesn't work in [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do/358993#358993).*

```js
const movieListEl = document.querySelector(".shows");
const moviesForm = document.getElementById("movie__searchbox");

async function main(event) {
    const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
    const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
    const data = await search.json();
    movieListEl.innerHTML = data.Search.map((movie) => movieHTML(movie)).join("");
}

// check when the form is submitted
moviesForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    const searchBarValue = document.getElementById("searchbar").value; // get input's value everytime the form is submitted
    console.log(searchBarValue);
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent refresh
    // localStorage.setItem("key", searchBarValue);
    // const searchKey = localStorage.getItem("key");
    main(searchBarValue);
});

function movieHTML(details) {
    return `<div class="shows__content">
        <figure class="shows__poster">
            <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
        </figure>
           <div class="poster__description">
            <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
            <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        `;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id="movie__searchbox" class="nav__search-bar">
    <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="nav__search" placeholder="Search" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<div class="shows"></div>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3sw8gkm9/) for a working version using local storage.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

By accessing `event.target.value` in the `browse` function, you're getting the value of the form instead of the value of the input.

### Potential Solution

I edited your snipped and gave the input a name of `searchbarinput` so that the `browse` function could reference it by name.

**Note: I only commented out the `localStorage.setItem` so that the example would run on Stack Overflow**

### Alternative:

You could also pass the form (`event.target`) to the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) constructor.

```js
    const movieListEl = document.querySelector('.shows');
    const searchKey = localStorage.getItem("key");
    
    async function main (event) {
        const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
         const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
        const data = await search.json();
        // console.log(data.Search)
        movieListEl.innerHTML = data.Search.map((movie) => movieHTML(movie)).join("");
    
    }

    main(searchKey);

   function browse(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.elements.searchbarinput.value);
        //localStorage.setItem("key", event.target.value); 
    }
    
    function movieHTML (details) {
    return `<div class="shows__content">
        <figure class="shows__poster">
            <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
        </figure>
           <div class="poster__description">
            <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
            <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        `
    }
```

```html
   

         <form action="" id="movie__searchbox" class="nav__search-bar" 
         onsubmit="browse(event)">
        <input type="text" name="searchbarinput" id="searchbar" class="nav__search" placeholder="Search" />
        <button type="submit"  > 
      Search</button>
        </form>
     <div class="shows"></div>
```

Comment: Probably comment `const searchKey = localStorage.getItem("key");` too.